# ColdFusion 10 vs ColdFusion 2018 - output speed difference

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-2016

I have 2 servers.  One is running ColdFusion 2018 Enterprise, the other is running ColdFusion 10 Enterprise.  The CF10 server is being upgraded to 2018 very soon.  I have a script that makes a database call and then builds a large XML document from the result of that query.  The process uses the  tag.

On my CF2018 server, the script finishes very fast, within seconds.  However, on my CF10 server it takes several minutes to finish.  I don't understand why though.  The amount of data is the same.  Both servers point to the same database for this, and I've checked the response time for the  on both to confirm my problem is not with the query.  I even copied the resulting XML into separate files and placed them on each server so I could call them directly from my browser. When I do this, both load immediately.

This leads me to believe the problem is with CF10 and the cfxml tag.  Does anyone have any documented information on this or why it looks to be SOOO much slower in CF10?

I compared everything from server to server on CFIDE and they are identical settings-wise.  The only difference I see is in the Summary the CF10 server is using **java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar**, whereas the CF2018 is using **java-xmlbuilder-1.1.jar**

Help!?!?

**UPDATE**

I thought I'd try removing the  tag and instead building my own with .  The result is the same.  It takes FOREVER on CF10, but in CF2018 it's almost immediate.

**UPDATE**

Continuing to test, I've found that the slowness in CF10's response is not bound to outputting the generated XML, but rather just CREATING the XML is the problem.  No matter if I use  or  - the creation process is the problem and causes CF to hang.

Comment: Do you have any sample code? Or more importantly when moving from one server to another the JVM and settings are the same? Usually when I do these kinds of migrations, a newer JVM and more memory happens too.

Comment: What version of Java is running on the new server vs. old? Does the new server have more RAM allocated per instance? Faster CPUs? Generally speaking, each version of CF is faster than the previous. You're jumping 3 versions (11, 2016, 2018), you should be complaining if CF 2018 was slower.

Comment: Can you post the code that's generating the XML file? Could be a buffering issue. Are you writing to memory and then to disk once the file is complete or are you creating the file and appending data?